# What can cause locationOnScreen_x to be different from the value returned by View.getX()?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm attempting to use a SurfaceView to manually draw some borders that snake around a few UI views (for practice) and I'm using `View.getX()`, `getY()`, `getHeight()`, and `getWidth()` to make sure that the lines are drawn correctly on different screens.

The problem is that the borders are being drawn offset from where they need to be. The relative placement of the lines is correct, but they just need to be shifted down and to the right.

I investigated the problem by using the Android Device Monitor to get the "Layout" > `locationOnScreen_x` and the "Drawing" > `x` variables and noticed that they were different. `locationOnScreen_x` shows the correct value of 70, while `x` shows 0.0. I assume that `getX()` returns the `x` value, which I apparently don't want.

My question then is two-part:

1. How can I programatically retrieve `locationOnScreen_x` instead?
2. What factors can cause `x` to differ from `locationOnScreen_x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by realizing that `getX()` returns the X value **relative to the parent *View*** and not relative to the device's screen.